# Camera movement And GUI Button Unity Android

Tags: android, camera, unity-game-engine

Here is my problem , i have a camera that i move right , left , down and up with Touch in android device , and i have a gui button who shows me a text when i double tap on it. The problem that when i touch the gui button , the camera move. I want when i touch the gui button , the camera stops moving and when i touch anywhere else in the screen the camera moves.

Here is my code:

```
public float tapSpeed = 0.5f;
private float lastTapTime = 0;
public Touch touch;
public Vector2 startPos;
public Vector2 endPos;
public bool fingerHold = false;

private float CameraYLimitUp;
private float CameraYLimitDown;
private float CameraXLimitRight;
private float CameraXLimitLeft;
public GUIText guiTextTap;

void Awake()
{
    CameraYLimitUp = 0;
    CameraYLimitDown = 27;
    CameraXLimitRight = -15;
    CameraXLimitLeft = 22;
}

void Update()
{
    // Camera moves left right up down with touch 
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
         touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            startPos = touch.position;
            fingerHold = true;
            print("touch began");
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            endPos = touch.position;

        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            fingerHold = false;
            print("touch end");
        }
    }

    if (fingerHold)
    {
        float deltaX = endPos.x - startPos.x;
        float deltaY = endPos.y - startPos.y;
        bool horizontal = false;

        if (Mathf.Abs(deltaX) > Mathf.Abs(deltaY))
            horizontal = true;

        if (horizontal)
        {
            if (deltaX < 0 && transform.position.x < CameraXLimitLeft)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 20);
            else if (deltaX > 0 && transform.position.x > CameraXLimitRight)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 20);
        }
        else
        {
            if (deltaY < 0 && transform.position.y < CameraYLimitDown)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 20);
            else if (deltaY > 0 && transform.position.y > CameraYLimitUp)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 20);
        }
    }
}

void OnGUI()
 {
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(480 , 289.5f , 100, 100), "GUI Test"))
      {
           if ((Time.time - lastTapTime) < tapSpeed)
            {
                Debug.Log("Gui Button Taped");
                guiTextTap.text = "Gui Button Taped";
            }
                lastTapTime = Time.time;
      }

 }
```

I Uploaded my project , you can find it here : https://mega.co.nz/#!0EkHQRDI!yDcUfJR_B5poXokku7fExOc-NtlDyYDeTCaBiAePzMs

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Checking the GUI hot control id would solve that issue, i.e. if the value of [GUIUtility.hotControl](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIUtility-hotControl.html) is greater than 0, it means that the user holds down a button. Hence, you could simply modify your if statement as below to bypass the camera movement when the user presses down the button:

```
void Update()
{
  ...
  ...

  // Check additionally if the GUI button is currently free
  if (GUIUtility.hotControl == 0 && fingerHold)
  {
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```